# Emulate network congestion / lag on node.js when using streams

Tags: node.js, tcp, stream

I need to know what is the best way to test a Node.js application using the native TCP server, and while using pipe, that can emulate lag or congestion of simultaneous connections and reads, or timeouts / packet loss to see if my implementation is stable enough to accomodate those problems without crashing.

Can this test be made with node.js or I need an external program for such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a newly released NPM module called https://github.com/dominictarr/pull-randomly-split that does emulate it, sort of. Since sockets are just streams, this does the job, along with some jitter or a real slow stream simulator, by the same author https://github.com/dominictarr/modem-stream